# VBA to select and copy cells into txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I need some assitance with creating some code to split 80k lines of data into chunks of 999. I have a dataset which is over 80k row. I only need column A, but I need to split the 80k rows of column a into chunks and save into a notepad txt fil. Is there a way of selecting a1:a999 copying and pasting into a that txt, then returning to excel and selecting a1000:a1999 selecting and copying into txt file again, then a2000:a9999, a3000:a3999 an so on until I have x number of txt files.

The spreadsheets already exists the problem i speak of here refers to 1 year I have spreadsheets for another 5 years all of which have in excess of 80 rows.

The outcome im looking for is to shorten the time of manually copying the data across to txt file. I need to do this as a colleague is using the txt file to enter the data into a query in SQL to remove data from a database. I have been told the particular query has limited the number to 999

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks Ted

Comment: `a1000:a1999` is 1000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by looping through each row in groups of 999 rows.

**Result:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
Sub RangeToTxt()

Dim FilePath As String, ClData As String
Dim frow As Long, lrow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

frow = 1
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet1

FilePath = "G:\Till\" 'Set path to txt files

k = 1 'Row to start from
For i = frow To lrow Step 999 'loop from first to last row. For every loop, jump 999 rows
    Open FilePath & k & ".txt" For Output As #1 'Set file
    
    For j = 1 To 999 'Loop through rows
        If Cells(i + j, "A") = "" Then Exit For
        ClData = ClData & Cells(i + j, "A") 'Append to data
        If j <> 999 Then 'If last row then skip extra line
            ClData = ClData & vbNewLine
        Else
            ClData = ClData
        End If
    Next j
    
    Print #1, ClData    'Write to txt file
    Close #1            'Close txt file
    
    k = k + 1           'Add 1 to txt file name
    ClData = ""         'Clean data

Next i              'Next group

MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent does exactly what I need.  thanks

Comment: Feel free to [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) the answer as accepted, by clicking on the grey tick mark below the voting buttons :). Lovely that it helped you. Might need some minor adjustment to fit your needs 100% :).